# I am making a bot using discord.py and I am stuck with mentions

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make it so that when I mention a user like for eg: !hello @user. The bot responds with Hello @user.

I would appreciate all help. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you're saying, i will give two different answers you can choose which its closer to.

So for mentioning a different user than you, like `!hello @otheruser` it would be:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {member.mention}")
```

error message for command above:

```py
@hello.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error,):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):       
       await ctx.send(f"Hey {ctx.author.mention}, thats the incorrect use! Please do `!hello @ user`.")
```

but for pinging the author of the message, it would just be:

```py
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello {ctx.author.mention}")
```

not really any error you can have with this.

`Any questions feel free to reply!`

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting but could you give me an example without the context functions because i dont use them.